# Filter MySQL result w/ empty row

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched high and low to filter my mysql query but WHERE NOT NULL does not work. I hope somebody could help me. I have some columns that are empty named 'path'. And I want to filter these out.

My query:

```
SELECT 
p.path, p.title, p.body, p.post_date, u.username FROM pages p 
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.post_author = u.id 
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

How can I get this done? Thanks.

Comment: When you say that the columns are *empty*, what do you mean?  What do they actually contain?  Can you show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE pages`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    p.path, p.title, p.body, p.post_date, u.username 
FROM pages p 
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.post_author = u.id
WHERE 
    p.path IS NOT NULL AND 
    p.path <> ''
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```

So does this help or you are asking something different?

Comment: I got it like this right now: `SELECT p.path, p.title, p.body, p.post_date, u.username FROM pages p LEFT JOIN users u ON p.post_author = u.id WHERE p.path IS NOT NULL ORDER BY p.id ASC` but it still doesn't filter out the empty path rows.

Comment: So are they empty or NULL? Add it like this then: `SELECT 
    p.path, p.title, p.body, p.post_date, u.username 
FROM pages p 
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.post_author = u.id
WHERE p.path IS NOT NULL AND p.path <> ''
ORDER BY p.id ASC`

Comment: That worked Andrius, thank you very mutch. I learned something new today!

Comment: Edit `WHERE p.path IS NOT NULL` to `WHERE p.path IS NOT NULL AND p.path <> ''`.

Answer (score 0):

try with php to check the empty field:

```
$query = "SELECT 
    p.path, p.title, p.body, p.post_date, u.username FROM pages p 
    LEFT JOIN users u ON p.post_author = u.id 
    ORDER BY p.id ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){

// Check for empty record
if( !empty($row['path']) ){
    echo $row['path'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, this might work.

```
SELECT 
p.path, p.title, p.body, p.post_date, u.username FROM pages p 
LEFT JOIN users u ON p.post_author = u.id 
WHERE p.path IS NOT NULL AND p.path <> ''
ORDER BY p.id ASC
```